# Route my form action into a custom function created inside a resource controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

In my web.php,

```
Route::get('studentmarksheet/addit','StmarksheetController@addit');

Route::resource('studentmarksheet','StmarksheetController');
```

I created a custom function addit() inside StmarksheetController. I have a form inside a view where I need to pass values to that addit function. For default functions inside my resoource controller, I used to call by

but, while trying to pass form values in addit function, it says route not defined. What exactly should I write? I have tried

```
{{route('studentmarksheet/addit')}}
{{route('studentmarksheet@addit')}}
```

and various other combinations.

I am a total beginner and I don't even know if am questioning this correctly. Please share your answers/suggestions/tips and so on, I would love to read them all.

Comment: name your routes and call .or else change {{url('studentmarksheet/addit')}}
{{url('studentmarksheet@addit')}}

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#named-routes

Answer (score 2):

First you need to name a route

```
Route::get('studentmarksheet/addit','StmarksheetController@addit')->name('stmarksheet.addit');
```

Then call it

```
{{route('stmarksheet.addit')}}
```

Resource route are named for you by Laravel

Comment: Thanks! I was confused how name() actually works. This cleared so much of my doubt. Learned something new :)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't set any name for the `addit` route. So, you need to write your route as like.

```
Route::get('studentmarksheet/addit','StmarksheetController@addit')->name('stmarksheet.addit');
```

And then you can get it in the view.

```
{{ route('studentmarksheet@addit') }}
```